# Getting TypeError: Return value error on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4

Need help,

getting

```
TypeError: Return value of Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterfaceFactory::create() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterface, instance of Sendinblue\Sendinblue\Model\Transport returned in /workspace/happyhottubs/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/TransportInterfaceFactory.php:53
```

Sendinblue di.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <!-- for override magento default Transport class with our custom module model-->
    <preference for="\Magento\Framework\Mail\Transport" type="Sendinblue\Sendinblue\Model\Transport"/>
    <preference for="\Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterface" type="Sendinblue\Sendinblue\Model\Transport"/>
</config>
```

Please help me how I can fix it on Sendinblue extension end.
Thanks

Comment: we can not provide support for 3rd party modules.

Comment: Thanks @PhilippSanderbut can you suggest something in order to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Update vendor/sendinblue/module-sendinblue/Model/Transport.php with

```
namespace Sendinblue\Sendinblue\Model; 
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface; 
use Magento\Framework\Mail\MessageInterface; 
use Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterface; 
use Zend\Mail\Message; use Zend\Mail\Transport\SmtpOptions; 
use Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp; 

class Transport  implements TransportInterface {
```

Clear generated and hopefully they fix it in their next update

Comment: Worked for me in the error: 
[2022-08-11 16:56:20] main.CRITICAL: TypeError: Return value of Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterfaceFactory::create() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterface, instance of Sendinblue\Sendinblue\Model\Transport returned in /home/714548.cloudwaysapps.com/gyjywajszn/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/TransportInterfaceFactory.php:53

Answer (score 0):

I'm quickly look at extension and unfortunately it's really poor quality

Based on available on github source https://github.com/sendinblue/magento2-plugin/blob/master/Model/Transport.php,  `Sendinblue\Sendinblue\Model\Transport` implements `Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterface`. But maybe this is not actual codebase.

I suggest to review `Sendinblue\Sendinblue\Model\Transport` class and try to debug why instance of `Sendinblue\Sendinblue\Model\Transport` doesn't implement `Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterface`.

Comment: Module via Magento marketplace

vendor/sendinblue/module-sendinblue/Model/Transport.php

Doesn't extend TransportInterface

`class Transport {`

Does not use implements TransportInterface